# Angular-Formly - ng-if issue with fieldGroup generated form

Tags: angular-formly

If I am using fielGroups and I am adding an ng-if to the formly-form tag the form generated by fieldGoups will not be displayed (because if fails the parent ng-if test)

Here is the jsbin : http://jsbin.com/zufubo/edit

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! So one thing that `fieldGroup`s do is they copy all of the attributes from the parent `formly-form` onto their own (nested) `formly-form`. So what was happening is the `ng-if` was being copied. So the solution is to put the `ng-if` on a wrapping element. The form is sufficient. Like [this](https://jsbin.com/vixubuv/edit?html,js,output):

```
<form ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" name="vm.form" novalidate  ng-if="vm.fields.length">
  <formly-form model="vm.model" fields="vm.fields" options="vm.options" form="vm.form">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" ng-disabled="vm.form.$invalid">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.options.resetModel()">Reset</button>
  </formly-form>
</form>
```